# How to keep label indentation with clang-format?

Tags: c, clang-format

Clang-format removes the indent on `goto` labels. Using `// clang-format off` is not preferred. How do I configure clang-format to not change the indentation of labels in the config-file?

**Desired output**

The labels are indented to match the code in the function. And they *should stay* in that indent.

```
int new_foo(foo **bar) {

  *bar = malloc(sizeof(foo));
  if ( !bar ) {
    goto failed;
  }

  goto done;
  failed: {
    return -1;
  }
  done:
  return 1;
}
```

**Actual output**

This is what clang-format actually produces. It's undesirable because it breaks indentation folding.

```
int new_foo(foo **bar) {

  *bar = malloc(sizeof(foo));
  if ( !bar ) {
    goto failed;
  }

  goto done;
failed: {
  return -1;
}
done:
  return 1;
}
```

**Update**

When using `IndentGotoLabels: false` (or `true`) in the `.clang-format` config this is the result. Note the `done:` and `failed:` labels are shifted left.

```
int new_foo(foo **bar) {
  *bar = malloc(sizeof(foo));
  if (!bar) {
    goto failed;
  }

  goto done;
failed : { return -1; }
done:
  return 1;
}
```

Contents of `.clang-format`.

```
IndentGotoLabels: false
```

Command is `cat test.cc | clang-format` and run in the same directory where `.clang-format` is present.

Comment: I asked the question because I couldn't find an answer from the documentation. You do not need to be patronizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: my initial answer was wrong.

It looks like regardless of how `IndentGotoLabels` is set goto labels are not indented on the same level as code is. Consider the following code snippet:

```c
int new_foo()
{
    {
        int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (!p)
            goto first_label;

        int *q = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (!q)
            goto second_label;

        return 0;

        first_label:
        return 1;
    }

    second_label:
    return 2;
}
```

Using the following configuration:

```
---
Language:        Cpp
IndentGotoLabels: false
TabWidth: 4
...
```

Running `clang-format` will give us:

```c
int new_foo() {
  {
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (!p)
      goto first_label;

    int *q = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (!q)
      goto second_label;

    return 0;

first_label:
    return 1;
  }

second_label:
  return 2;
}
```

If we change `IndentGotoLabels` to `true` we have:

```c
int new_foo() {
  {
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (!p)
      goto first_label;

    int *q = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (!q)
      goto second_label;

    return 0;

  first_label:
    return 1;
  }

second_label:
  return 2;
}
```

The labels are now indented, but are on the same level as the `{` that starts the code block, not the code itself.

I don't know if this is something that `clang-format` can not do, or I'm missing some option. I'll keep my answer posted even if it does not actually solve the problem. It might prove to be useful.

This is also the documented behavior, if we look at the examples in the documentation, so there might not be a way to change it.

This falls into opinion territory, but `clang-format` can be quite limiting at times. If you have the freedom of using another code formatter [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html) might do what you want with `--indent-labels`.

**Initial answer:**

Set `IndentGotoLabels` to false in your `.clang-format` file. See [the documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for more information.

If you don't have a `.clang-format` file you can generate one based on a predefined style:

```
clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > .clang-format
```

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example? Sample code and config? I don't think it can un-indent already indented labels (I can't check this right now).

Comment: I updated the original question with how `IndentGotoLabels` does not work. I am version 10 btw.

Comment: I completely misunderstood the question, I'm sorry. I edited my answer, but it looks like `clang-format` still does not do what you need it to do (or I can't find the right option).

Comment: For my eyes it's good style to indent labels on the same level as the containing block.

Comment: After reviewing clang-format's source I believe this is the best answer. Thank you for the `astyle` suggestion.